# NodeJS - Local scope has already been closed (fatal error)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, v8, npm

When I run my node app, I get this error message before it quits:

> FATAL ERROR: v8::HandleScope::Close() Local scope has already been closed

By hunting around on the google groups, one theory I have is that I have a node module version conflict.  But I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Note: I have another socket.IO server running on this machine.  Could that be the culprit?

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var express = require("express");

    var app = module.exports = express.createServer(),
        util = require("util"),
        socketIO = require("socket.io"),
        connect = require("connect"),
        Room = require("./rooms/models").Room,
        User = require("./users/models").User,
        Abuse = require("./abusers/models").Abuse,
        guid = require("./utils").guid,
        forceLatency = require("./utils").forceLatency,
        latencyWrap = require("./utils").latencyWrap,
        config = require("./config"),
        log = require("./log"),
        mergeStatic = require("./mergeStatic"),
        geoip = require("geoip"),
        httpdigest = require('http-digest'),
        authServer = require('./authentication/server').authServer(),
        feedbackServer = require('./feedback/server').feedbackServer(),
        dnode = require("dnode");



    var registerAppRoutes = function(app) {
      //code code code
    }

    function registerSocketIO(app) {
        // code code code

    }

    mergeStatic(function (jsHash, cssHash) {

        app.helpers({
            jsHash: jsHash,
            cssHash: cssHash
        });

        registerAppRoutes(app);
        registerSocketIO(app);

        app.listen(config.port);        
        util.puts("Server started on port " + config.port);                

    });


}());
```

Comment: No one can help you without posting your code. It is common sense :)

Comment: Not necessarily.  My app file is huge, and it's working totally fine on another machine.  In fact, it's working fine on this machine - I'm just starting the app up on another port (for staging purposes) and it breaks.

Comment: But still, we can't guess how to solve your conflict without seeing what the code looks like.

Comment: OK, I updated the post with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so my hunch was right.  I cleared out my node_modules directory with rm -rf and ran "node app.js" and then "npm install modulename" over and over until all my dependencies were fixed up. Can't wait til node evolves a great dependency management solution!

Now everything's working.